# ext-imagick * -> the requested PHP extension imagick is missing from your system

Tags: php, laravel, imagick, homestead

I have trouble installing devisephp for laravel. I am working on the latest version of homestead with php7. when i do composer update i get the following error.

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for devisephp/cms 1.4.* -> satisfiable by devisephp/cms[1.4.0].
    - devisephp/cms 1.4.0 requires ext-imagick * -> the requested PHP extension imagick is missing from your system.
```

After having this message i installed imagick on my homestead environment added the extension to php.ini in cli and fpm and checked in homestead if imagick is working with a test file. Everything was working perfectly but on running composer update i still get the same error message from above. Does anyone have a clue what the problem can be.

The stange thing is that is kan git clone devisephp its bootstrap version completely working including image handling but when i add another package to laravel i again get the above message.

Comment: SO `php -v` will output PHP 7.0.* and `php -m | grep imagick` will output `imagick`?

Answer (score 25):

if you really can't install or don't want that extension to be validated you may skip it by supplying the

`--ignore-platform-reqs`

flag to your composer command

Comment: Wow, I wish I had found this a long time ago. Would have saved me a lot of pain -- I sometimes need to composer-install packages just to have my local PHPStorm play ball, but I don't need them to actually work locally. I just need the code completion / intellisense benefits.

Comment: This option helped me  while struggling to find a solution for extension issue. Many thanks.

Comment: One can also use the `config.platform` setting to fake the dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67919544/814031

Answer (score 17):

Please follow these steps

- **sudo apt-get install php-imagick**
- **php -m | grep imagick**     // this should print 'imagick' it means installed correctly
- **sudo service apache2 restart**  //(if needed)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
"ext-imagick": "*",
```

to your **require** block in your composer.json like so:

```
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "ext-imagick": "*",
    ....
}
```

and run **composer update**

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Mac, here are the steps:

1. Install Image Magick dependency.

   `brew install pkg-config imagemagick`
2. Compile Imagick PHP extension with pecl

   `pecl install imagick`
3. Verify the installation.

   `php -m | grep -i magic`

   You will see `imagick`.

Answer (score 1):

my solution with PHP8.3 and imagemagick

brew reinstall php
brew reinstall pkg-config
brew reinstall imagemagick

sudo pecl uninstall imagick (in this case sudo was the solution)

pecl install imagick

#PHP8.3

Answer (score 0):

With the `config.platform` key in composer.js you can fake dependencies like php versions or extensions (you can't use an asterisk for the extension version, though!)
https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

As a bonus, you can polyfill ext-imagick with this library: https://github.com/calcinai/php-imagick. it's not complete and relies on the command line ImageMagick. So far it works for me.

```json
{
    "require": {
        "calcinai/php-imagick": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
      "platform":{
        "ext-imagick": "3.4.4"
        }
    }
}
```