# spatie/pdf-to-image 1.8.2 requires ext-imagick Error in composer install

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, imagick

I am just picking up one legacy laravel project by using composer cli.
I executed `composer install` but it's saying one Error `spatie/pdf-to-image 1.8.2 requires ext-imagick Error`.
I couldn't figure it out.
I guess it's because imagick extension wasn't set properly in php.ini.
Anybody has ever faced on this kind of error before?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ext-imagick \* -> the requested PHP extension imagick is missing from your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829419/ext-imagick-the-requested-php-extension-imagick-is-missing-from-your-system)

Comment: No, I couldn't solve the problem through the answer.

Comment: Do you have the imagick extension installed for your PHP installation? What is your platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't have the Imagick extension installed on your machine.
Also you should make sure you have uncommented out Imagick.so in `php.ini`.
You can follow up the next steps if you are using macOS.

First, install **imagemagick** itself. This is needed to get the source files you’ll use later to compile the PHP extension with.

```
brew install pkg-config imagemagick
```

This will also install the needed **pkg-config** dependency.

Second, use **pecl** to get the PHP extension compiled.

```
pecl install imagick
```

It will also auto-register itself in your **php.ini** and should now be available

Lastly, test imagick extension would be available.

```
php -m | grep -i magic
```

This command would show `imagick` if it's properly set out.

Note: if you run **php-fpm**, make sure you restart your daemon to load the latest extension. Use `brew services restart php`

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, you simply do not have php extension imagick that is used in "spatie/pdf-to-image" that you are trying to use.

You can check if imagick is installed with function `phpinfo();`

Installation / activation depends what system you are using.

Under Ubuuntu you can install it with single command:

```
apt-get install php-imagick
```

Whatever system you are using, make sure that imagick is not already installed and just commented in php.ini